# Converting Managed String to std:string using marshal context

Tags: c++, string, character-encoding, c++-cli, marshalling

I am aware of the post: [Converting managed System::String to std::string in C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789807/converting-managed-systemstring-to-stdstring-in-c-cli) for the required conversion. But I came across the following code which uses `marshal_context` instead. I am trying to understand how it works.

```cpp
// required header : #include <msclr/marshal.h>
System::String^ str = gcnew System::String(L"\u0105");
msclr::interop::marshal_context ctx;
auto constChars = ctx.marshal_as<const char*>(str);
std::string myString(constChars);
```

If I am not wrong `str` is a single "character" represented by 16 bits using UTF-16, which according to the [Unicode list](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0105/index.htm) is a small Latin letter `a` with an ogonek. But `myString` comes out to be a single character `?`. How does this conversion happen?

Moreover why does code work as "expected" when creating `str` with a an ASCII character say `a`. In UTF-16 `a` would be represented in 16 bits, with most/least (depending on endianess) significant 8 bits being all `0`. Why does then `myString` have only one `char` `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a sequence of `char`s. A `char` can typically only hold ascii characters (in 8 bit). It can overflow when assigned a unicode character value that can exceed 8 bits. When it overflows you get a "garbaged" value.

You need [`std::wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which contains a sequence of `wchat_t` to represent a unicode string.

Therefore change your last 2 lines to:

```
//-------------------------------------vvvvvvv--------
auto constChars = ctx.marshal_as<const wchar_t*>(str);

//---vvvvvvv----------------------
std::wstring myString(constChars);
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks. But I am more interested in why/how the above happens

Comment: Added an explanation why `std::string` will not work in this case.